# High-resolution VR with tethered smartphone display

Tags: unreal-4, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I have an Android SmartPhone with a fairly high resolution + USB-C port, a USB-C-to-USB-A cable, and a Google Cardboard headset.

Is it possible to develop a VR app running on a PC game engine (such as Unreal) but stream the output to the Cardboard headset by using the phone as a display? (rather than running the app entirely on the phone). For instance, if I wanted to render using a beefy NVIDIA GPU and stream the graphics over USB.

What are the options here? I'm aware of this guide, which seems reasonable: https://uploadvr.com/budget-vr-101-get-pc-vr-streaming-phone/

Is this a use case supported by any Game Engines like Unreal/Unity?

Comment: Not out of the box. Unreal source code is accessible so it can be added. Unity probably not, unless you purchase a license that allows source access.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workable solution: developing a Daydream/Cardboard App using Instant Preview (https://developers.google.com/vr/tools/instant-preview) allows Unity / Unreal Applications to be rendered locally on the desktop and be streamed over to the smartphone. This is good enough for prototyping.

Comment: Glad to see that you found a solution! Don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - it helps others who may run into the same or similar problems.